# Codeigniter 3: Don't reload form on form validation error

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm new with codeigniter. I have this form and in the end of the form the user have to re-enter his password for confirmation, however, the page reloads if the password was incorrect and all the data that the user typed on the input field disappeared. Is there a way for the validation_error to output without the page reloading?

**Here's my view form** **SHIFTER.HTML**

```
<?php echo form_open('forms/submit_form');?>              
<div id="form-interview-fill-mainform">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Strengths:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control form-input" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" rows="1" name="shifter_answer[]"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Weaknesses:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control form-input" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" rows="1" name="shifter_answer[]"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="custom-form">
       <?php
        if(validation_errors()){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-lable="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong><?php echo validation_errors()?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php  
        }?>
        <label>Password</label>
        <center>
        <?= form_password('password','','class="form-control" id="password" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;" required');?> 
        </center>
    </div>
     <center><?php echo form_submit('submit','Submit Form', 'class="btn btn-success btn-lg"');?></center>
    </div>
</div> 
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**Here's the controller**

```
public function submit_form(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|callback_check_pass');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==false){
        $this->load->view('shifter.html');
    }else {
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
    $givenAns= $this->input->post('shifter_answer');

    foreach($givenAns as $ansKey => $ansVal){
        $ansKey+=16;
        $ids []= $this->forms_model->shifter_form_submit($data['id'],$ansVal,$ansKey);
    }
    redirect('profile/forms','refresh');
    }


}

 function check_pass($password){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('forms_model');
    $result = $this->forms_model->val_password($data['id'],$password);
        if($result){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_pass', "Invalid Password");

            return false;
        }
}
```

**And here's the model**

```
 function val_password($id,$password){
         $this->db->select('id,password');
        $this->db->from('tbl_st_account');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows()==1){
                return $query->result();
            }else{
                return false;
            }    
      }
```

Comment: hi, if you want to repopulate the form you can do this [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form) with the form you has, but if you want to send the form without load page, yo need to use ajax, and with it repopulate the form values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is reloading before the server even performs the validation. You'll need to use AJAX. AJAX the request. On failed validation, have the AJAX callback pop a message to the user. On successful validation, have the AJAX callback direct the user to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to preserve the value, you can re-populate it using set_value() function. try this following code :

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

here set_value() parameter and and textbox name should be same.